# How to get the link coordinates in EBookDroid of Android for opening the links programmatically

Tags: android

I'm developing a EBookreading application, EBookDroid is a library which we are using for the PDF reading. If we have any links in the PDF like [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com), when the user clicks on it, it supposed to open the link, for that i need to find out the coordinates of that link in the Document.
I am writing like the below.

```
final RectF linkRect = page.getLinkSourceRect(pageBounds, link);
```

But it's always giving the null back.

Comment: show me what u have tried...

Comment: Its a EBookDroid library which iam using. 
This is the method which iam using.
Every PDF contains the http urls right, i need to find out the co ordinates of that link. It is referring to MuPDF library internally for this purpose. But each time whem iam calling the fillPageLinkSourceRect(linkHandle, temp), its always returning null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be use full

[THIS EXAMPLE](http://polamreddyn.blogspot.in/2013/03/high-lite-specific-text-in-android.html)

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for the reference, it helps me for the EPUB reader, but for the current issue, it cant. The PDF reader is not using the Webview for rendering. :(